# apache rewriterules

Tags: mod-rewrite

How can I match a url like that:

1/2/3/

it means:

1 = http:// www.mysite.com

2 = may be mypage or my-page

3 = may be myparam1 or myparam-1 or my-param-1

--> 1 should be pre-defined

--> 2 and 3 may contain only letters or alphanumeric or alphanumeric plus one hyphen or two (-)

I need a reqular expression to use with htaccess to rewrite a url to another url with some $_GET params.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ foo?1=$1&2=$2
```